# ld: warning: ignoring duplicate libraries: '-lgcc' after the recent update of Xcodebuild tools

Tags: c++, xcode, gcc, g++, xcodebuild

Recently, I upgraded to Xcode 15, and with that the update of the xcodebuild tools. However, suddenly, my standalone C++ applications are not able to use the g++-13 compiler for some reason? Anyone knows what might work, I don't want to downgrade to Xcode 14.

Comment: It says "warning", so it is not going to prevent linking. Please provide a complete [mre].

Comment: It's the conflicts between Xcode CLT 15 and Homebrew which you uses to install g++-13. One option is to downgrade to Xcode CLT 14.

Comment: I have a very similar message after installing Xcode 15.0. It says `Ignoring duplicate libraries: '-lc++', '-lsqlite3', '-lz'`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From Apple's internal employees, this is the fault of Homebrew, you can either wait for Homebrew to fix it or try other ways to install GNU tools.

Comment: Is it safe to ignore the warnings?

Comment: More details at https://github.com/orgs/Homebrew/discussions/4794#discussioncomment-7044468. (10-Sep-2023) "Yes, this is an incompatibility of current gcc with the Xcode 15 and/or CLT 15. The warning is not a problem, and we will ship a fixed version in the future."

Answer (score 11):

Update 2023-11-05: Some users reported problems after ignoring this warning, see the [answer by danny below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77244391/1743580).

---

The Homebrew team responded to the GitHub issue [ld: warning: ignoring duplicate libraries: '-lemutls_w', '-lgcc' #4794](https://github.com/orgs/Homebrew/discussions/4794#discussioncomment-7044468) on Sep 19, 2023, with:

> "Yes, this is an incompatibility of current gcc with the Xcode 15 and/or CLT 15. The warning is not a problem, and we will ship a fixed version in the future."

A commenter asked here on SO:

> Is it safe to ignore the warnings?
> (from a commenter)

Yes. To get rid of the warnings, what worked for me was [the suggestion](https://github.com/orgs/Homebrew/discussions/4794#discussioncomment-7117550) to add the following linker flags for gcc:

```
-Wl,-ld_classic
```

`ld_classic` is the old Mach object file link editor.

> The ld_classic command combines several Mach-O (Mach object) files into one by combining like sections in like segments  from  all  the  object       files,  resolving external references, and searching libraries.  In the        simplest case several object files are given, and  ld_classic  combines        them,  producing  an object file which can either be executed or become        the input for a further ld_classic run.  (In the latter  case,  the  -r        option  must  be given to preserve the relocation information.)  Unless        an output file is specified, ld_classic produces a  file  named  a.out.        This file is made executable only if no errors occurred during the link        editing and there are no undefined symbols.
>
> (excerpt from [man page](https://www.manpagez.com/man/1/ld_classic/))

Answer (score 2):

## A Workaround

If you'd like to silence the warning in the meantime, add this line exactly as-is to the `other linker flags` in your project's build settings within Xcode:

```
"-Wl,-no_warn_duplicate_libraries"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that Xcode and gcc are the only thing causing this . I have the same issue with ld: warning: ignoring duplicate libraries: '-lgcc'

I have it running on one system building with no issues and get the above error on another. I am using gcc-13 on both systems and they have the same version of Xcode. Now the working system has the whole xcode but the new system does not. The main difference of these systems is the working one is intel and the other is the mac default chip. However, I do not see how the would effect it.

I tried ld-classic info above but it still fails. It causes my built to fail. I did have -wall set but I removed that and it still dies.